# how to write Maven dependency on sub-module of a package

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm at the beginning to move to Maven so I have no pom.xml at the moment. My project depends on only a subset of modules of another project which is not mine. They have the list of modules listed in their pom which is distributed. How do I state the dependency on the specific jars (which presumably are contained in the downloaded jar) in my pom.xml?

Comment: Do you want to share some snippets from both pom.xml files and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm at the beginning to move to Maven so I have no pom.xml at the moment. I want do define a dependecy on a published project, but only a few submodules of it.

Comment: What is the relation between you project and that project? Is that project parent or dependency of your project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your other project is organized into sub-maven-modules with their own `pom.xml`, then the `<groupId>`, `<artifactId>`, `<version>` nodes of these sub-maven-modules will be included as  in your main project.

E.g.

```
project 1
  |- common
       |- pom.xml
          <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
          <artifactId>common</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
  |- util
       |- pom.xml
          <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
          <artifactId>util</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
  |- domain
       |- pom.xml
          <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
          <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
  |- service
       |- pom.xml
          <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
          <artifactId>service</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
  |- webapps
       |- pom.xml
          <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
          <artifactId>webapps</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
```

In project 2, if you just want only the `common`, `util` and `domain` and domain modules, then pom.xml for this project would contain the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    ...

    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
          <artifactId>common</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
          <artifactId>util</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
          <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    ...

</dependencies>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Project 2 is from other people, and I just see that they have the list of modules in the pom which is distributed. Does your answer work too with that setup?

Comment: you mean project 1 is from other people?

Comment: If i understood correctly, yours is a maven project with multiple sub modules and you want someone else to just use only those sub modules they are interested in, right?

Comment: Vice versa, but looking at it, it don't seem to matter, anyway, so I'll accept your solution after a waiting period. Thanks!